# could not convert string to float from file.txt

Tags: python, string, numpy

I'm trying to read from a file a string-array and convert it into a float array. To sum up, I'm trying to do something like:

```
input_X = np.random.rand(2, 5)

with open ("prueba1.txt", "w") as fichero:
    fichero.write(str(input_X))

with open("prueba1.txt", "r") as fichero:
    x = fichero.read()


y = np.array(x)
y = y.astype(np.float)
```

And then:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[4.17022005e-01 7.20324493e-01 1.14374817e-04 3.02332573e-01\n  1.46755891e-01]\n [9.23385948e-02 1.86260211e-01 3.45560727e-01 3.96767474e-01\n  5.38816734e-01]]'
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: The `str` of a numpy array is meant to show you the array values and layout.  It is awkward, if not impossible, to recreate the array from it.  It isn't meant to be a file saving format.  Look at the `np.save/load` pair of functions instead.

Comment: `astype(np.float)` can convert an array like `array(['1','2','3'])`.  The individual elements of `y` have to be strings that look like valid numbers.  `float('1')`.  But that's not what you load.  Look at `x` and `np.array(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
input_X = np.random.rand(2, 5)
np.savetxt('prueba1.txt', input_X)
y = np.loadtxt('prueba1.txt')
```